# How to add Arabic language in TinyMCE?

Tags: javascript, tinymce

I have a TinyMCE editor on my form, but when I insert Arabic it doesn't work: Arabic characters change to ='?????????'.

Here is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>/tinymce/tinymce.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    tinymce.init({
        mode : "specific_textareas",
        editor_selector : "mceEditor",
        convert_urls: false,
        plugins: [
            "advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview anchor",
            "searchreplace visualblocks code fullscreen",
            "insertdatetime media table contextmenu paste"
            ],
            toolbar: "insertfile undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | link image"
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Does your browser normally display Arabic characters?

Comment: yes of course, but when I insert Arabic it doesn't work: Arabic characters change to ='?????????' in the database, & in my view too

Answer (score 1):

Have you downloaded and specified the language font for tinyMCE?

- http://www.tinymce.com/i18n/
- http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/TinyMCE3x:Language

---

```
tinyMCE.init({
    language : "ar_SA", // arabic
    mode : "textareas",
    theme : "simple"   
});
```

Comment: yes i've use that, but it doesn't work, is that just change the lane toolbar of my tynimce editor from right to left r(rtl)

Comment: @RizkiFahrizal have you tried this example. http://fiddle.tinymce.com/baaaab Does this do what you expect?

Comment: hmm i think no, maybe i just wrong a question. in my opinion, i just want to insert Arabic character from my tynimce editor into database, but  Arabic characters change to ='?????????', this problem from tynimce or what ?

Comment: I don't think it's a problem with TinyMCE. What encoding are you using on your server?

Comment: i've use framework codeigniter, and my encoding is $db['default']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
$db['default']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';